# assign list to python object

Tags: python, oop

I have a file to read from, that looks like:

```
  0.0017224129699045  0.0006501069699993  0.9998957781816742
  0.1990018751753198  0.0008531972943402  0.0001365339587167
  0.3985306090674854  0.0004447825187626  0.9994454487115476
  0.5997635306734566  0.0007689624538330  0.0001887505556155
  0.8014083650919446  0.0007156269856168  0.9995317401042954
  0.1999636426048639  0.1995427045657650  0.0017775030876521
```

Each column shows coordinate of an atom. I want to assign coordinates to the atom defined as an object in python:

```
# The parser
#!/usr/bin/python3
def get_pos():
    with open("CONTCAR", "r") as finp:
        for line in finp:
            for _ in range(6):
                sdata = finp.readline()
                tpos.append(sdata.split())

    print(tpos)
```

And the calling function is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import parsepos

class Atom:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, name, pos=[], vel=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        Atom.count += 1
        # self.parse = parsepos.get_pos()
parsepos.get_pos()
```

This  `mcwe`, shows the atoms are listed properly, in `list tpos`, but I don't know how to assign those value to `atom.pos`.

Kindly help.

Comment: Using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python3` will find the Python interpreter no matter where it's installed...

Comment: Why not `atom.pos = whatever`?

Comment: `Atom.pos = parsepos.get_pos()
print(Atom.pos)` yeilds `none`

Comment: Aside: using mutable default arguments like `pos=[]` can lead to problems, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a function in Python returns `None`. Just make `get_pos()` returning `tpos`:

```
def get_pos():
    with open("CONTCAR", "r") as finp:
        for line in finp:
            for _ in range(6):
                sdata = finp.readline()
                tpos.append(sdata.split())

    # print(tpos)
    return tpos
```

and then like this:

```
Atom.pos = parsepos.get_pos()
print(Atom.pos)
```

Hope this helps!